# TComPort - Delphi Xe7

Tags: delphi, arduino, porta-serial

Preciso de um componente que consiga ler porta serial, estou fazendo uma aplicação integrando com o arduino.

Vi que existe o Tcomport, porem não consigo instalar no Delphi xe7, alguém ja conseguiu??

Erro: 
[dcc32 Fatal Error] CPortLibDXE7.dpk(34): E2202 Required package 'vcl' not found

Comment: Eu consegui uma vez, mas só que utilizando o Embarcadero C++ XE8. O que vc precisar fazer é recompilar todo o projeto novamente dentro da sua IDE Delphi XE7.

Comment: Então, o problema é justamente quando tento recompilar..

Comment: Eu fiz um tutorial passo a passo de como fazer essa recompilação, mas não estou com ele agora, posso postar para vc amanhã, pode ser?

Comment: Sim, se puder agradeço, Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

**Passos para a instalação ComPort no CodeGear Embarcadero C++ Builder 2009**

Antes de começar a instalação, caso ainda não possua os arquivos do **ComPort**, você pode encontra-los no link abaixo:

[Download TComPort](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/comport/comport/4.11/comport411f.zip?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fcomport%2Ffiles%2Fcomport%2F4.11%2F&ts=1446546322&use_mirror=superb-dca2)

Eu realizei a compilação utilizando o **CodeGear Embarcadero C++ Builder 2009**, mas para a versão que você necessita os passos a seguir são semelhantes.

**1º** -> Descompacte o arquivo ***"comport411f.zip"*** na pasta de instalação do C++ Builder ***"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\ComPort"***. Os arquivos que devem estar dentro deste diretório são os que estão na pasta ***'source'***.

**2º** -> No C++ Builder, adicione a pasta descompactada contendo os arquivos da **pasta 'source'** em: ***"Tools->Options...->Environment Options->Paths and Directories->Library Path"*** e adicione o caminho: ***"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\ComPort"***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**3º** -> No C++ Builder, clique em: **"File->Open..."** e entre em **"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\ComPort"** e abra o arquivo **"CPortLibCB6.bpk"**. O programa irá pedir para atualizar o projeto, clique em Ok.

**4º** -> No C++ Builder, clique em: **"Project->Make CPortLibCB6 Ctrl+F9"**. Após compilar, clique em Ok.

**5º** -> No C++ Builder, clique em: **"File->Open..."** e entre em **"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\ComPort"** e abra o arquivo **"DsgnCPortCB6.bpk"**. O programa irá pedir para atualizar o projeto, clique em Ok.

**6º** -> No C++ Builder, clique em: **"Project->Make CPortLibCB6 Ctrl+F9"**. Após compilar, clique em Ok.

**7º** -> Copie os arquivos de **extensão .dcu** da pasta **"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\ComPort\Debug_Build"** para a pasta **"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\RaveReports\Lib"**

**8º** -> Copie os arquivos de **extensão .obj** da pasta **"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\ComPort\Debug_Build"** para a pasta **"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\lib\obj"**

**9º** -> Copie os arquivos de **extensão .bpl** da pasta **"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\ComPort"** para a pasta **"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\bin"** e para a pasta **"C:\Windows\System32"**

**10º** -> Copie os arquivos de **extensão .hpp** da pasta **"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\ComPort"** para a pasta **"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\include\vcl"**

**11º** -> No C++ Builder, clique em **"File->Close All"** e não salve o projeto.

**12º** -> Feche o C++ Builder e abra-o novamente.

**13º** -> Crie um projeto novo em **"File->New->VCL Forms Application - C++ Builder"**.

**14º** -> No C++ Builder, clique em **"Component->Install Packages->Add"** escolha os dois **arquivos .bpl** da pasta **"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\ComPort"**. Um erro ocorrerá, e clique em Ok. Depois clique em Ok novamente.

**15º** -> Insira o componente **'TComPort1'** da paleta **'CPortLib'**.

**16º** -> Agora compile o projeto **"Project->Make CPortLibCB6 Ctrl+F9"**, dois erros de multiplicidade irão ocorrer. Comente as linhas em que isso ocorre.

**17º** -> Pronto! Agora comece a utilizar esta biblioteca.

Para mais informações a respeito, segue abaixo link para download da documentação do **ComPort**.

[Documentação TComPort](http://www.elfaforums.lv/attachment.php?attachmentid=781&d=1226581239)